# Attempted to call method "getClientId" on class "ArrayObject"

Tags: payum

I'm using Payum 0.12 + Paypal Express Checkout and got this error on complete action:

> Attempted to call method "getClientId" on class "ArrayObject" in
>   DetailsController.php on line...

Here is controller code:

```
<?php
namespace Custom\CustomBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Payum\Core\Registry\RegistryInterface;
use Payum\Core\Security\HttpRequestVerifierInterface;
use Payum\Core\Exception\RequestNotSupportedException;
use Payum\Core\Model\OrderInterface;
use Payum\Core\Request\GetHumanStatus;
use Payum\Core\Request\Sync;

class DetailsController extends Controller
{
  public function completeAction(Request $request) {
    $token = $this->get('payum.security.http_request_verifier')->verify($request);

    $payment = $this->get('payum')->getPayment($token->getPaymentName());

    try {
      $payment->execute(new Sync($token));
    } catch (RequestNotSupportedException $e) {}

    $payment->execute($status = new GetHumanStatus($token));

    /** @var OrderInterface $order */
    $order = $status->getModel();

    return $this->render('CustomBundle:Default:complete.html.twig', array(
      'status' => $status->getValue(),
      'order' => htmlspecialchars(json_encode(
        array(
          'client' => array(
            'id' => $order->getClientId(), //<--- Error here
            'email' => $order->getClientEmail(),
          ),
          'number' => $order->getNumber(),
          'description' => $order->getCurrencyCode(),
          'total_amount' => $order->getTotalAmount(),
          'currency_code' => $order->getCurrencyCode(),
          'currency_digits_after_decimal_point' => $order->getCurrencyDigitsAfterDecimalPoint(),
          'details' => $order->getDetails(),
        ),
        JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE
      )),
      'paymentTitle' => ucwords(str_replace(array('_', '-'), ' ', $token->getPaymentName()))
    ));
  }
}
```

Even if i use 'offline' payment option without Paypal Exress Checkout, i'm getting this error. Am i missing something maybe?

Comment: That's known issue: https://github.com/Payum/Payum/issues/251 and it was
fixed in 0.13 version (current dev). I'll try to back port it to 0.12 when
I find time.

Comment: Thank you. I tried to add this fixes manually. But for me it is still not working, must be i missing something maybe. Anyway thanks for the info.

Comment: After double checking, i finally found 1 mistake that i did, when i patched manually. Now everything is cool.

Comment: There was a fix for this case. Try to use `$order = $status->getFirstModel();` instead of `$order = $status->getModel();`.